# How to call out a variable in DoCmd.OutputTo code?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a variable that pulls from two textboxes where people enter their username and a number. Those variables are then used to create the title of a personalized table for them.

I want to export this table to excel, I just don't have the right syntax to call out the variable.

When I run this line of code the export title is 'all', which is not a table that exists.

Thanks for the help!

```
Dim nm As String
   nm = Text41.Value
   Dim nb As String
   nb = Text43.Value
all = "" & nm & "" & "_" & "" & nb & ""
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "[ 'all' ]", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "", True, "", , acExportQualityPrint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, then your variable `all` holds the final name of the source table. So instead of

```
 "[ 'all' ]"
```

you should use

```
all
```

So the resulting line of code would be:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, all, "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "", True, "", , acExportQualityPrint
```

Comment: i actually tried that first, it exports a table called [] which also doesn't exist,
Here's the line that does that:
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "[" & all & "]", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "", True, "", , acExportQualityPrint

Comment: I got it to work! The code declaring the variable wasn't in the sub! The syntax above is correct without the brackets: "" & all & ""

Comment: Fine. So if the square brackets are superfluous, you can just use `all`. I will edit the answer.